# lsusb returns "permission denied" in Termux

Tags: root-access, usb, permissions, termux, selinux

When I run `lsusb` in Termux, the output is `permission denied`. I don't have root access.

Perhaps the Android system allows me to get specific access in root?

Comment: @Irfan Latif is it possible to get a specific root access in an unrooted device? Temporary root access with a password ,for example,would be amazing for customers! Android might be more flexible ...

Comment: No (un)fortunately that's not possible. Android by-design doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 1):

`lsusb` command lists entries in `/sys/bus/usb/devices` which is world-readable but SELinux would be denying access because `u:r:untrusted_app:s0` context isn't allowed to access `u:object_r:sysfs:s0`.

However you can try `adb shell lsusb` because sepolicy allows `u:r:shell:s0` to read the directory as defined [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r34/public/shell.te#168):

```
allow shell sysfs:dir r_dir_perms
```

And [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r34/public/global_macros#32):

```
define(`r_dir_perms', `{ open getattr read search ioctl lock }')
```

Comment: So,I tried 'adb shell lsusb' and this is the following output: $ adb shell lsusb No command 'adb' found, did you mean: Command 'ab' from package 'apache2' Command 'gdb' from package

Comment: [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) is to be run from PC. Follow [this](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCommandLine/article.html) simple guideline.

Comment: Using adb in an Android device, plugged in windows pc for example,have a way to run commands that wasn't allowed before in termux , whatever it will be,not only lsusb?(desmg,lsusb and some commands doesn't works too)

Comment: @J-Mello sorry can't understand what you mean.

Comment: I need to use a USB on a PC to make lsusb permissions be able.I've been wondering about,if I use termux(either on pc or in an Android device) in this scenario I would be able to use termux like my android device were rooted.